C++ Qt how to properly delete widget
If I created any widget something like QPushButton* btn= new QPushButton("Text",this); then does parent widget completely destroys all children widgets or just removes them from it`s internal list?
Should I just use delete btn; or I need to use btn->deleteLater(); to completely destroy it? What the difference between this functions?

hould I just use delete btn; or I need to use btn->deleteLater(); to completely destroy it? Either will work. The first removes it now, The second removes it when your function ends and the event loop can process.

The doc says "The new widget is deleted when its parent is deleted."

In my code I use all 3 methods depending on the situation. Sometimes you want to remove a child widget now.  Maybe the parent widget needs to live longer then the children and the child widgets can be removed to save memory. Sometimes you need to wait for the event loop because of some dependency. Other times you can let the parent free the children.  I would say that letting the parent free the children is the most common method I use and deleteLater() is the least common.

There are plenty of results even by just doing a basic research. The difference is also relatively clear, from the deleteLater() docs ("Schedules this object for deletion"), which should also be considered when an object may be relatively complex, and/or has unexpected relations (eg. item model based objects) or need proper deletion due to their event handling. In any case, the object would be deleted; the question is: is there something that actually worries you?


does parent widget completely destroys all children widgets or just removes them from it`s internal list?

The parent widget will destroy all children widgets. From the
QWidget::QWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags()) documentation:
QWidget -> QAbstractButton -> QPushButton

If parent is nullptr, the new widget becomes a window. If parent is another widget, this widget becomes a child window inside parent. The new widget is deleted when its parent is deleted.


Deleting any QObject subclass, including any QWidget subclasses, will delete all its children too. This is the basis of Qt QObject memory management and object ownership, you should really read QObject documentation, when learning Qt.
If you do deletion from code which may be called from the object itself, then you should use deleteLater(). For example, if deletion happens in a slot or lambda, which is directly called by clicking the button, then you shouldn´t use delete to delete the button, because the instance is actually executing a method (which sent the click signal).
deleteLater() does deletion from the Qt event loop, so object can not be executing its own method while it is being deleted.
If you are deleting any C++ object from a method of the object itself, then using delete directly is generally asking for trouble. It can be ok, but even if it is ok now, future code changes may break it without developer noticing. deleteLater offers a nice way to do the deletion safely for QObject subclass objects.
